# How do we define an abstract basis-independent trace operation?

Tags: definition, tensors, trace

In this [wikpedia page on Abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation) for tensors, it states that $t_{ab}{}{}^b$ denotes an "abstract basis-independent trace operation". I understand that this index notation doesn't refer to numerical indices and is basis independent. However, I haven't been able to find a definition of the abstract basis-independent trace operation. E.g. it seems that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator) is something unrelated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. The trace is basis-independent in the sense that any choice of basis gives the same result, but I think you do need _some_ (finite) basis in order to definite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb{F}$, we can always consider the natural evaluation mapping $\epsilon:V\times V^*\to\Bbb{F}$, given as $\epsilon(v,f):=f(v)$. Then, $\epsilon$ is clearly bilinear, so by the universal property of tensor products (which is in fact one of the cleanest, but abstract, ways to define the tensor product), there is a unique linear mapping $\epsilon':V\otimes V^*\to\Bbb{F}$ such that for all pure tensors $v\otimes f$, we have $\epsilon'(v\otimes f)=\epsilon(v,f)=f(v)$ (i.e such that 'the obvious' diagram commutes). This is the definition of the contraction/trace mapping.

By reasoning similarly, given vector spaces $V,V_1,\dots, V_k$ over a field $\Bbb{F}$, we have the linear mapping $\text{tr}:V\otimes V^*\otimes (V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_k)\to V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$ such that for all pure tensors,
\begin{align}
\text{tr}(v\otimes f\otimes v_1\otimes\cdots \otimes v_k)&=f(v)\cdot\,v_1\otimes\cdots
\otimes v_k
\end{align}
Typically, the $V_i$'s are one of $V$ or $V^*$. So, whenever you have a tensor product space whereby in the factors, a vector space and its dual both appear, you can define a trace/contraction over those slots.

Now, we can ask the question of how to define the trace of an endomorphism $T:V\to V$. Well,  assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional, one can prove (using a basis) that the natural mapping $V\otimes V^*\to \text{End}(V)$ (whose action on pure tensors is $v\otimes f$ being mapped to the endomorphism $x\mapsto f(x)\cdot v$) is actually an isomorphism. In this case, the trace/contraction mapping on $V\otimes V^*$ induces a corresponding map on $\text{End}(V)$. This is precisely the trace of an endomorphism as defined in linear algebra (i.e take a matrix representation relative to some fixed basis, and then sum the diagonal entries).

Comment: Is there a name for this isomorphism $V \otimes V^* \to End(V)$? I'd like to look it up. Also, is there a more general isomorphism between $V_1 \otimes .... \otimes V_n \otimes V^*_1 \otimes ... \otimes V^*_m$ and $V_1 \times .... \times V_n \to V_1 \times .... \times V_m$, where by the latter I mean $Hom(V_1 \times .... \times V_n, V_1 \times .... \times V_m)$?

Comment: @user56834 The most general is if $V,W,X$ are vector spaces then the mapping $\text{Hom}(V,W)\otimes X\to \text{Hom}(V,W\otimes X)$ given (again using universal property) as $f\otimes x$ being mapped to $[v\mapsto f(v)\otimes x]$ is a vector space isomorphism if $V$ is finite-dimensional. From this, it follows that $(V_1\otimes V_2)^*\cong V_1^*\otimes V_2^*$ (assuming both finite-dimensional). Another consequence is that $V^*\otimes W\cong\text{Hom}(V,W)$ (assuming $V$ finite-dimensional)

Comment: As a further corollary, assuming $V_1,\dots, V_m,W_1,\dots, W_n$ are finite-dimensional spaces, we have $V_1^*\otimes\cdots V_m^*\otimes W_1\otimes \cdots \otimes W_n\cong (V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_m)^*\otimes (W_1\otimes \cdots \otimes W_n)\cong \text{Hom}(V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_m,W_1,\otimes\cdots \otimes W_n)$. I suggest you try to prove all these special cases from the first isomorphism I mention (at times you may find it helpful to write $V^*=\text{Hom}(V,\Bbb{F})$, and note that $\Bbb{F}\otimes W\cong W$ for any $W$).

Comment: Of course, throughout all tensor products are over the same field $\Bbb{F}$. As for a name, I'm not too sure. I'd probably search along the lines of "tensor product commutes with Hom isomorphism". In fact all of this holds for modules over a commutative ring $R$ (where a module $M$ being finite-dimensional just means $M\cong R^{\oplus n}$ for some integer $n\geq 0$).

Comment: Took me some time to understand this but now I mostly do! Thanks!